# ACF (Autocorrelation) estimation

Tags: data-mining, time-series, sequential-pattern-mining

I have two signals "Signal A" and Signal B" and I plot the autocorrelation for each signal with itself as shown below. How I can determine which signal has a stronger correlation with itself. 
To calarify more, I want to answer this question : "Which signal is more correlated with itself "Signal A" or Signal B" ?

[image]

Comment: Apart from looking at the graph where the first is clearly more autocorrelated? You coul try a Durbin-Watson test to get p-values.